# Personal investment and yearly capital taxation

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax, ireland

Regarding someone based in Ireland.

If a private person saves regularly and invests in stocks, how can she grow the investment and pay taxes some day in the future when she withdraws from her account?

Does she necessarily need to pay yearly capital gain taxes (basically restraining growth)?

Would creating a holding company somewhere in Europe solely for this purpose be viable?

Comment: As a general rule, capital gains (or losses) occur when an asset (say, the shares that you hold) are _sold_; the gain (or loss) because of an increase (or decrease) in the _market value_ of the stock is ignored by the taxman.  Is Ireland so different from most of the rest of the world? Or are you misunderstanding the Irish tax rules?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: yes, in Ireland the rules are exactly as you describe them. But I was wondering if a private person could buy/sell at will and receive dividends from these stocks through a company without worrying of taxes, until withdrawing from the company. That is, reinvesting without paying CGT.